# Can I use ASIHTTPRequest to access SVN?

Tags: ios, objective-c, svn, asihttprequest

Any idea if it is possible to use ASIHTTPRequest methods to access SVN through MAC OS X app? If so how do I use SVN commands through HTTP requests?

Comment: What is the point in using asynchronous HTTP requests on SVN repository?

Comment: Ya. Thats an interesting question. I was trying to figure out a way to pass credentials to SVN through a MacOSX app. Tried to use NSTask for default svn commandline, but did not succeed. Thought ASIHTTP can be an option.